# How many rows in a SQL Server table is too much?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012, bigdata, openstreetmap

I am parsing and storing some OSM (open street map) data in a SQL table, using Entity framework.

I've estimated there will be around **11 million records** in this table. Which will be bound a to a model with EF etc. Is this too many?

What can I do to make this amount of data useable and not too slow?

Comment: No, these are not too many. Use indexes to speed it up.

Comment: Its not too many if your hardware is up to the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of rows in the DB is not the deciding factor regarding EF usage. What does become an issue with EF is when you need to work with many records at once. If you regularly manipulate many records at once, eg insert 10k, delete 10k, or update 10k at once, daily, then you will want to use SQL stored procs.

With Context, context objects and proxies and even change tracking, all nice with small transactions, large volume activity becomes slow.

My personal rule of thumb is around 1000 objects loaded at once. Use direct sql.
I use direct SQL side by side EF.  I use EF for 95% of activity.
For data loads, extracts, table copies etc, all with SQL scripts/Sps.

Also Since EF6 you can tell EF to add extra indexes beyond the foreign keys, so that SQL generated performs ok.

Comment: You can disable a lot of those things for bulk writes.